# Legendre symbol, what is it?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, quadratic-residues, legendre-symbol

I am reading wiki article about [Legendre symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_symbol) and I don't understand the power meaning. Can you please explain the next expression.

$$\left(\frac ap\right)\equiv a^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\pmod p$$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews tnx, first covered.

Comment: It's the usual definition of exponentiation; $\frac{p-1}{2}$ will always be an integer because $p$ is odd.

Comment: It would really help if you were specific about what you are asking. Do you know what $a\equiv b\pmod p$ means, for example? What is confusing you? Are you really asking us to explain what the expression means, or are you asking us to explain why the expression is true?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I am asking what the expression means. This is a definition of new symbols and I am just trying to make sure that I am reading it right and it's the same power that I know and not new definition with the new Legendre symbol. I just trying to understand what is Legendre symbol and how to use it. Sorry if my question may sims to trivial.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since  you say you have read about Legendre symbol on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_symbol), you should already know that $\left(\frac{a}{p}\right)$ is defined as $0$ if $p\mid a$ and as $\pm1$ for $p\nmid a$, depending on whether $a$ is a quadratic residue modulo $p$ or not.

According to [Euler's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_criterion), the congruence
$$\left(\frac{a}{p}\right) \equiv a^{(p-1)/2}$$
holds for any odd prime $p$.

There is nothing mysterious about the expression $a^{(p-1)/2}$, it is just a usual exponentiation. (It is useful to notice that $(p-1)/2$ is a positive integer if $p$ is an odd prime.)

Let us have a look on specific examples. For $p=5$ we have $(p-1)/2=2$ and we get
$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
a & a^2 & \left(\frac{a}{5}\right) \\\hline
    0 & 0 & 0 \\\hline
    1 & 1 & 1 \\\hline
    2 & 4 &-1 \\\hline
    3 & 9 &-1 \\\hline
    4 &16 & 1 \\\hline
  \end{array}
$$
If you look at the second and third column, they are indeed congruent modulo $5$.

For $p=7$ we get the following table:
$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
a & a^3 & \left(\frac{a}{7}\right) \\\hline
0 & 0 & 0 \\\hline
1 & 1 & 1 \\\hline
2 & 8 & 1 \\\hline
3 &27 &-1 \\\hline
4 &64 & 1 \\\hline
5 &125&-1 \\\hline
6 &216&-1 \\\hline
\end{array}
$$
(We know that quadratic residues modulo $7$ are $(\pm1)^2\equiv1\pmod 7$, $(\pm2)^2\equiv4\pmod 7$ and $(\pm3)^2\equiv2\pmod 7$.)

You may notice that instead of calculating $a^3$ we might calculate $a^3\bmod 7$, which would is a bit easier. For example $5^3=5^2\cdot 5 \equiv 25 \cdot 5 \equiv 4\cdot 5 \equiv 20 \equiv -1 \pmod 7$.

---

This is more about the the basic properties of [congruences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) rather than about the Legendre symbol, but I will try to explain the previous computation, per [request in a comment by the OP](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1635987/legendre-symbol-what-is-it/1636006?noredirect=1#comment3336061_1636006).

The only thing we are using here is the fact that if $a_1\equiv b_1\pmod n$ and $a_2\equiv b_2\pmod n$, then also $a_1b_1\equiv a_2b_2\pmod n$.

Using this rule we know that 
$$25\cdot 5\equiv 4\cdot 5\pmod 7$$
since $25\equiv 4\pmod 7$.

In fact, we have even easier way to calculate $5^3 \bmod 7$. If we notice that $5\equiv -2 \pmod 7$ then
$$5^3 \equiv (-2)^3 \equiv -8 \equiv -1 \pmod 7.$$

For more about similar computations, have a look at [How do I compute $a^b\,\bmod c$ by hand?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81228/how-do-i-compute-ab-bmod-c-by-hand) and [other related posts](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/81228).

Comment: I don't understand the last part of your answer. And this actually what I been searching at the first place. I asked about it [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1635706/quadratic-reciprocity-tell-if-c-got-quadratic-square-root-mod-p)

Comment: By the last part, you mean the one starting: "You may notice that instead..."? (BTW I think that if, for some reason, the answer is not sufficient for you, you probably should not have accepted it. The green tick sends a message to other potential answerers: "The OP is already satisfied with the existing answers." There is no reason to be hasty with accepting one of the answers.)

Comment: Yeah, how do you make the calculation of the big power easier.

Comment: @Ilya_Gazman I have tried to add some explanation and also a link to other post(s) which might help you with this.

Comment: Big big big tnx I am reading it now.