# Is there integer $x$ such that $79|7x^2+4x-23$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, quadratic-residues, legendre-symbol

Is there integer $x$ such that $79|7x^2+4x-23$ ?

I keep getting that there is $x$ that satisfies this condition, but online calculator keeps saying that there is not. 
I worked it out using Legendre's symbol:

If $y=7x+2$, then starting equation is equivalent to $y^2 \equiv 7$ mod$79$,
and because $\genfrac{(}{)}{}{}{7}{79} = \genfrac{(}{)}{}{}{79}{7} = 1$, equation has a solution ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Quadratic reciprocity: Tell if $c$ got quadratic square root mod $p$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1635706/quadratic-reciprocity-tell-if-c-got-quadratic-square-root-mod-p)

Answer (score 1):

Note that by quadratic reciprocity
$$
\left(\frac{7}{79}\right)=(-1)^{3\cdot39}\left(\frac{79}{7}\right)=-\left(\frac{2}{7}\right)=-1.
$$

Comment: Oh my god .....